# Notifications on low balance of a bitcoin address

Tags: wallet

Is there a service or wallet where I can subscribe my email address to notifications on low balance on my bitcoin address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[blockonomics](https://www.blockonomics.co) will mail / send you push notification whenever there is transaction on your address. Doesn't have a feature for low balance yet, but should be straightforward to implement.